# How to use current date time in xamarin forms date picker?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, datepicker

I have a xamarin App applying for leave. The student should apply to leave within 3 days from the day they took leave. If they take leave on 03-oct-2020 then they should apply to leave on or before October 6. I am using the calendar for selecting a date and setting the maximum date as today and a minimum date as Today -3. So the last remaining days won't be available. It's working. But when the student set the device date manually to any past date. Then the calendar in the app also changed to that date. How could prevent this?

Please help me on this

Comment: you will need to check against some external time source - either a time server, or your own server will need to validate the data when it is submitted

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little sample to get date from internet and not depending on your local machine

View :

```
<StackLayout>
   <Label x:Name="dateLabel" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
   <Button Text="Get Date" Clicked="Button_Clicked" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = httpClient.GetStringAsync(new Uri("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Kolkata")).Result;

                ServerDateTime sDateTime = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServerDateTime>(response);

                dateLabel.Text = sDateTime.datetime.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
            }
        }
```

Model

```
public class ServerDateTime
    {
        public string abbreviation { get; set; }
        public string client_ip { get; set; }
        public DateTime datetime { get; set; }
        public int day_of_week { get; set; }
        public int day_of_year { get; set; }
        public bool dst { get; set; }
        public object dst_from { get; set; }
        public int dst_offset { get; set; }
        public object dst_until { get; set; }
        public int raw_offset { get; set; }
        public string timezone { get; set; }
        public int unixtime { get; set; }
        public DateTime utc_datetime { get; set; }
        public string utc_offset { get; set; }
        public int week_number { get; set; }
    }
```

A little side note on the *cleartext HTTP* issue:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/164771/cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted